# Why does this generator expression raise a syntax error?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, any

This line throws an error saying I didn't define `x` even though I stated that `x` is an element of the list:

```
any(i.isdigit() for i in x for x in [name.id for name in all.names])
```

So `x` is a string element of the list, and I am checking if for some character in each element `x`, that element `x` contains a number using `.isdigit()`. How come this doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comprehensions/generator expressions in Python nest from left to right (yeah, it can be a bit confusing). Swap them:

```
for x in [name.id for name in all.names] for i in x
```

Or separate out for clarity:

```
def contains_digit(s):
    return any(c.isdigit() for c in s)


any(contains_digit(name.id) for name in all.names)
```